# Merging millions of polylines into single unique polyline

Tags: python, gis, geojson

I am trying to figure out an ***efficient*** way to calculate the uniqueness of millions of paths. i.e. calculate coverage.

I have millions of [(lon,lat),...] points, that represent paths taken around a given city.

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to calculate unique millage. So points from one side of the street cancel another out, or paths that are heading in different direction cancel each other out, etc. Leaving only 1 path representing that a given area has been walked.

Now I can loop through the dataset, adding points to a new list, while also comparing that new point's distance to all points in the new list, and if its within a certain radius consider it none unique, and don't include it.

This is slow.

This has to be a solved problem, but alas I can not find anything helpful online as of yet. Does anyone have an recommendations, formulas, or any general advice on merging [(lon,lat),...] paths, to represent unique coverage in miles?

Comment: I think this might fall under [optimization problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem)

Answer (score 0):

Since your intermediate goal seems to be reducing the number of points in your polylines and they are conveniently situated in a city, you could try [map matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_matching) them to known streets and paths to achieve that. [This GIS SE question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/5761/45164) might be helpful in that regard.